# CSS-Grid and Hover Text

Tags: html, css, hover, css-grid

I'm trying to figure out how to make a hover effect with text in CSS Grid. I want the text to appear in the middle of each grid but I can't seem to be able to do it yet.

So far I've managed to get the hover effect by doing this:

```css
.productName {
  opacity: 0;
}

.firstArea > .product:hover {
  opacity: .3;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

But then I changed that code to what's bellow so I could show the text in the middle of each individual grid but with no avail.

```css
.product .productName {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  transition: .5s;
}

.product:hover .productName {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I think that's happening because I set `.product .productName` as a flex item plus of the position I gave to the item, but right now I'm a little burnt out and can't think of another solution…

So if anyone could help me with this it'd be a great help! Here's the link to the codepen.io so you guys can see the whole thing.

https://codepen.io/cfervir/full/JLwgVb

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.firstArea {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(180px, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.firstOne,
.product {
  background-color: #00b9e2;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.productName {
  color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.product:hover .productName {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="firstArea">
    <div class="firstOne">
      <div>Hi there!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test A</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test B</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test C</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test D</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Extra: Is it possible to make empty tables appear in CSS Grid in smaller screen widths? For example, when I shrink the window "white spaces" appear and I'd like to be able to have empty grids in there (with the same color, border, etc… but nothing will happen if I hover over them).

Comment: use property: "text-align": "center"

Answer (score 0):

```css
.firstArea > .product {
  background-color: #00b9e2;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.firstArea .product a {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.product .productName {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .firstArea > .product:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 2/3;
  }

  .firstArea > .product:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 3/4;
  }

  .firstArea > .product:nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: 4/5;
  }

  .firstArea > .product:nth-child(5) {
    grid-column: 5/6;
  }
}

.firstArea > .firstOne {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #00b9e2;
}
```

Here, a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/10ztpckm/3/

```css
html {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* Section Start */

/* Here I set the Columns and Rows */

.firstArea {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(180px, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.firstArea > .product {
  background-color: #00b9e2;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.firstArea .product a {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.product .productName {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.product:hover .productName {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .firstArea > .product:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 2/3;
  }
  
  .firstArea > .product:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 3/4;
  }
  
  .firstArea > .product:nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: 4/5;
  }
  
  .firstArea > .product:nth-child(5) {
    grid-column: 5/6;
  }
}

.firstArea > .firstOne {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #00b9e2;
}

.firstArea > .firstOne > div {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="firstArea">
    <div class="firstOne">
      <div>Hi there!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test A</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test B</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test C</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test D</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I have a question tho, why the @media?

Comment: For the extra question :p (If I understood correctly)

Comment: Aaah. 

If you shrink the webpage you'll notice that the original 5 column layout changes to a 4 column layout and the 5th item moves to the bottom and to the right all you see is white space (and if you continue to shrink it you'll see it changes to a 3 column layout, then a 5 column layout and finally a 2 column layout).

I was wondering if you could give make all that white space go away and fill it with blue grids but with empty data.

Thanks again!

Comment: But you can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/qk7xfg0h/ (and then apply a media queries for little screen)

Comment: The thing this will be a dynamic gallery (with photos being added from time to time) an too many media queries could get misleading in the long run I think.

Comment: Gallery or not, it is imperative to have a responsive designe with a mobile display and a desktop display imo.

Comment: @Gwen Added syntax highlighting and copied your code to code snippet (external links can become invalid in future).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov thanks a lot, I edit with my last proposal with responsive design

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov fixed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to "flex" `.product` and get rid of the absolute positioning on `.productName`. I've gotten rid of some extraneous CSS rules to simplify things:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.firstArea {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(180px, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.firstOne,
.product {
  background-color: #00b9e2;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.productName {
  color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.product:hover .productName {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="firstArea">
    <div class="firstOne">
      <div>Hi there!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test A</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test B</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test C</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="productName">Test D</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

The main reason why I have `absolute` on `.productName` is because I plan to put a picture on each grid (200px height and width) and I believe it needs to be `absolute` if I want `.productName` to appear in front of said image when I hover over it.

But your answer helps me tons! Because I managed to advance on something that seemed to be trivial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display a div in center also the text inside it in center, then try this :

```
<style>
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align : center;
}
</style>
```

Apply this class on some div. If you dont want display div in center but only text, then you can change margin.